# Why is $O(x\log^{26} x\mathrm{e}^{-c\log^{1/10}x}) = O(x\mathrm{e}^{-c\log^{1/10}x})$ for big enough c

Tags: real-analysis

I read in [a paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~tonyfeng/riemann_zeta.pdf) (page 21) the following statement:

---

$O(x\log^{26} x\mathrm{e}^{-c\log^{1/10}x})$

By increasing $c$, we can take out the $\log^{26}x$ factor

---

Can someone explain how should be choose the new $c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but what should have been said in the paper is that the constant $c$ can be made **smaller**. Note that $c$ is introduced in Theorem 2.1.3. as

> There  exists  a  small  absolute  constant c > $0$ such that the
>   following is true...

That means making it smaller but still stay positive may be non-trivial. In addition, to prove the desired $O$-relation, we have to prove

$${x\log^{26}xe^{-c\log^{\frac1{10}}x}} \le M{xe^{-c_1\log^{\frac1{10}}x}}$$

for some $M$ and big enough $x$ and some new constant $c_1$ on the right hand side.

This is equivalent to

$${\log^{26}x} \le M{e^{(c-c_1)\log^{\frac1{10}}x}}. \tag{1} \label{eq1}$$

If we actually had $c_1 > c$ as the paper claims, the left hand side of the last inequality would tend to $\infty$ as $x$ increases, while the right hand side would tend to $0$, as the argument of the exponential function would tend to $-\infty$ as $x$ increases.

So, after clearing up that confusion, the goal is now, given some possibly very small positve constant $c$, to find an even smaller, but still positive constant $c_1$ that satisfies $\eqref{eq1}$, for $x$ 'big enough'.

---

We have, for $x \ge e$

$$e^{\log\log x}=\log x.$$

Since the $\log$-function increases slower than any (positive) power of its argument, even when multiplied by a positive coefficient, we have for some $x_0$:

$$\log \log x < \frac{c}{30}\log^{\frac1{10}}x, \forall x \ge x_0,$$

so we have

$$\log x = e^{\log\log x} < e^{\frac{c}{30}\log^{\frac1{10}}x}, \forall x \ge x_0.$$

That means

$$\log^{26}x < e^{26\frac{c}{30}\log^{\frac1{10}}x}=e^{(c-\frac2{15}c)\log^{\frac1{10}}x}, \forall x \ge x_0.$$

This is just the desired inequality $\eqref{eq1}$, with $M=1$ and $c_1=\frac2{15}c$.

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed $k$ and any $C < c$ $$O(x(\log^k x)\mathrm{e}^{-c\log^{1/10}x}) = O(x\mathrm{e}^{-C\log^{1/10}x})$$

For the prime number theorem we don't really care of the precise value of $C$, just that some $C > 0$ exists